# What are "all the rights and privileges pertaining thereto"?

Tags: united-states, degree, legal-issues

It is common language in graduation ceremonies, at least in the United States, to hear a degree conferred with "all the rights and privileges pertaining thereto." How would one discover what the rights and privileges pertaining to a MA or PhD degree actually are?

Comment: I think this should be tagged for a specific country. Such a statement sure wasn't uttered in any of the graduation ceremonies I attended in Germany, while receiving the degree actually does grant the recipient a particular right, namely that of claiming to have the degree.

Comment: That is indeed a non-trivial right. I edited the question to clarify that I heard the phrase primarily in the United States, but the question is more general than that; I'm not asking what the rights and privileges of a degree are, which certainly vary locally, but how do find out what they are in any particular setting.

Comment: It's just ritual theater, just like the striped robes and square hats and fake diplomas.  Or for that matter, the real diplomas.

Comment: Privileges in ritual theater are still privileges.

Comment: I agree with the others, this is going to depend a lot on the country you are in. One of the biggest rights and privileges is likely to be entry into certain files that have educational requirements before state recognition.

Comment: See also this question, which asks about the obligations: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/88278/what-are-my-obligations-as-an-msc-holder

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if some older universities actually have some interesting privileges sitting around in dusty old ancient rulebooks that were never formally revoked, e.g. perhaps grads are allowed to graze livestock on The Quad, wear a sword on campus, receive priority seating if taking an undergraduate class, or are entitled to one formal audience with the Dean every year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think any of the seven previous answers attempts to address the question from the body of the post:

> How would one discover what the rights and privileges pertaining to a MA or PhD degree actually are?

The first thing to do would be to check the university's website for its regulations, which may go by different names. E.g. in Cambridge they are [Statutes and Ordinances](http://www.admin.cam.ac.uk/univ/so/), and by reading them you can discover, for example, that both MAs and PhDs are members of the Senate (unless they have resigned or are suspended) and as such can vote in elections to the Chancellorship.

If you can't find the regulations, believe them incomplete, or need clarification on some point, then the next thing would be to write to the university. Again, the name of the body or title of the person equipped to answer the query probably varies: it would probably be reasonable to make an initial approach to the Alumni Office, the Dean's office, or the Vice-Chancellor's office, and to request that should their department not be the correct one that they point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 10):

Each of my diplomas says my degree is awarded "with all of its privileges and obligations" or something close to that.  I know of neither an official codification nor a learned treatment of the privileges and obligations involved.

But, along with Thomas Aquinas, C. S. Lewis, and Mr. Spock, as opposed to David Hume and Cmdr. Data, I hold that values are *logical*.  So I deduce that:

- The "privileges" include putting the degree on your curriculum vitae so you can get jobs requiring a degree;
- The obligations include honesty about the subject matter in which you are supposed to have some expertise.

Comment: You might be interested in reading [my answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/63732/12391) to a recent related question.

Comment: See also this question, which asks about the obligations: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/88278/what-are-my-obligations-as-an-msc-holder

Answer (score 3):

I would think the rights and privileges also includes the not necessarily actualized non-legal right/privilege to teach at universities and colleges (Sorry for the convoluted sentence -- I don't know how to simplify it).

Actualization of course requires being hired by some university and is not wholly exclusive to PhD and MA holders.

Comment: You're right. I have mentioned that (half-implicitly) with a further clarification in [my answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/63732/12391) to a recent related question.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: something that existed centuries ago in Europe, and not today, any more than one wears formal academic regalia.

Comment: +1 if you can articulate what those somethings are...or *were*.

Answer (score 2):

For the United States things are pretty limited, but generally the rights and privileges are going to be some sort of guarantee that the degree granting institution will verify that you were in fact awarded the degree in question. Since a lot of jobs now require degrees this is a non-trivial right. Additionally, alumni usually get some sort of perks such as library borrowing privileges, access to athletic facilities, etc. but that is very dependent upon the school.

Of varying use depending upon where you live you can use post-nominal initials to indicate the degree awarded and being addressed as "Doctor" if you were awarded a suitable degree. As noted in the [answer by jackbael](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/41736/7269), you also have the academic right to wear the regalia of the school from which you graduated.

Comment: In some countries, a degree confers the entitlement to use a title (such as Dr. Such and So, but also for lower levels) that is legally protected (people without the degree may not use the title, and **more importantly** unaccredited universities cannot grand them.

Answer (score 1):

While the rights and privileges are not always physical aspects they do indeed exist.  The right to wear Regalia (and the pride that goes with it), the fulfillment of a degree requirement for potential employers, the assumption that some degree of knowledge about the particular degree major exists, the legal aspect of holding a degree (and the fact that you can actually be jailed if you lie about some degrees, i.e. nursing, doctor, minister, etc), the privilege of moving on to the next step in your degree aspirations, i.e. masters, doctorate, etc. The degree process will open many doors that would not be opened if you lack a degree in some discipline.  Just a few thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

As for specific countries, both my degrees were obtained in Canada, and both diplomas bear that statement, although one got all hoity-toity, and the entire diploma is in Latin.
My understanding is the rights are to use the designation (is: BA, and BEd, in my case) on curriculum vitae and letterhead, etc. It also qualifies me to apply for a higher degree program.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I used to tell students assembled for commencement: "When the President of the University confers upon you your new degree, she will confer all the "rights, privileges, and responsibilities appurtaining thereunto."

Don't let that go unto your head.  You have almost no new rights nor privileges; you may add the initials of your degree after your name, but outside academia, and before the Ph.D., almost no one does that.

What you do have are the responsibilities of an educated person, one example of which is the responsibility to help others understand the social and political implications of what's going on.  That turns out to be a substantial amount of work.  So, enjoy your new status  and exercise your new responsibilities well!  We're proud of you, SPSU grads!"

Separately, the president specifically granted "the right to wear the hood appropriate to your degree," so, at least one actual privilege, although perhaps less important now than 600 years ago.

Comment: While not authoritative, I think this is the best answer to the question. Thanks for posting it.

Comment: Too bad nobody else liked it.  :(

Comment: Well, I can't make it positive, but I can at least raise it back up to zero for the time being.

Answer (score -1):

Given the Medieval origin, one right is not to have the authorities use thumb screws if you are subject to interrogation. Being able to write was deemed a valuable skill. I suspect other rights fall into these categories which are now extended to everyone through the Bill of Rights.

Answer (score -2):

to use the title granted for all your job searches and to receive henceforth the honors to be part of an elite, as a result of the level of education you have achieved by your efforts.
to offer a professional expertise as expected for the conduct of the professional tasks that will be asked to you during your professional career and to respect the code of ethics of the specific profession.

Comment: This seems copy-pasted from a specific certification, without attribution, but either way, the question is talking about generality.