# What are my obligations as an MSc holder?

Tags: masters, degree, bachelor

I hold two degrees, a BSc (2011) and an MSc (2013), from the University of Waterloo. I noticed recently that on my BSc it reads "[...] and has been granted admission to that degree with all the rights and privileges thereto appertaining.", whereas on my MSc it reads "[...] with all associated rights, privileges and obligations." I'm a bit curious about the difference. First of all, I wonder what these obligations might be. Off the top of my head I can think of a couple of rights and privileges that would apply to me as a degree holder, but nothing that I might be obligated to do occurs to me. A quick search for an explanation of the text didn't turn anything up either. I also wonder whether the association of obligations to the degree is peculiar to the MSc for some reason. Would also be curious about the ubiquity (or not) of such statements at other institutions.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question. I'm going to check my B.S. degree when I get home to see what it says (if anything) :) But if I had to guess, I'm assuming this is a disclaimer that they can revoke the degree in the future if it's shown that you plagiarized, falsified your grades/work, etc.

Comment: For the interested reader, see also https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41735/what-are-all-the-rights-and-privileges-pertaining-thereto.

Comment: I agree with @tonysdg - those obligations might include that you faithfully represent your degree, and in general uphold the reputation of the institution granting you the degree. I've never heard of those obligations being enforced post facto, though, only if the degree itself is obtained by some dishonorable method.

Comment: I bet most schools would love to add "donate to us!" as an implicit obligation....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some insight can be gained from considering the Oxford degree day ceremony, which is still conducted in Latin and uses fairly traditional formulae in admitting graduands to degrees. The descriptions used indicate various rights and responsibilities (all translations from [here](https://www.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxford/field/field_document/Degree%20ceremony_201617_web.pdf)):

Candidates for the DD, DCL, DM and MCh (all higher doctorates) swear to the following:

> Doctors (Masters or ladies/gentlemen), you shall swear
>   to **observe the statutes, privileges, customs and liberties
>   of this University**. Also when you shall have been
>   admitted to the House of Congregation and to the House
>   of Convocation you shall **bear yourselves in them well
>   and faithfully to the honour and profit of the University**.
>   And especially in those matters which concern Graces
>   and Degrees you shall **not impede the worthy or put
>   forward the unworthy**. Also at elections you shall **record
>   and nominate one only at one time and no more in each
>   scrutiny, and nominate no one unless you know certainly
>   or believe firmly that s/he is fit and proper**.

For other higher degrees:

> You shall swear to **observe the statutes, privileges, customs
>   and liberties of the University**, as far as they concern you.

They are then admitted to the degree by the Vice-Chancellor, with the wording (for the DD, DCL, DM and MCh):

> To the honour of Our Lord Jesus Christ, and for the profit
>   of our Holy Mother Church, and of learning, I, by my
>   own authority and that of the whole University, give you
>   licence to incept [begin to teach] in the Faculty of Arts (or
>   Faculty of Surgery, Medicine, Law or Theology) to lecture,
>   to dispute and to do all the other things that pertain to
>   the rank of Master (or Doctor) in the same Faculty, when
>   those things have been completed which the Statutes
>   require, in the name of the Lord – Father, and Son, and
>   Holy Ghost.

(A non-Christian formula is available if graduands request).

Other higher degrees have a formula either conferring permission to incept (begin to teach) in the faculty, or just admitting them to the degree.

For the MA, graduands swear an oath "binding them **to
be loyal, obedient and faithful to the University and its
interests, and to comport themselves circumspectly at
elections to University offices**" before being admitted by the Vice-Chancellor.

Finally, BA graduands are admitted with the following formula:

> Ladies/gentlemen, I admit you to the degree of Bachelor
>   of Arts: furthermore by my own authority and that of the
>   whole University, I give you the power of lecturing, and of
>   doing all the other things which concern the said degree.

To summarize, traditionally degrees were about membership in a Faculty of the university, and came with responsibilities to uphold the rules of the university, and participate fairly in elections. (These aren't empty words at Oxford, where they still confer 'MA status' on faculty members who do not have an Oxford MA so that they can participate in the governing bodies, and which still allows all graduates to vote on the Chancellorship and Professorship of Poetry). It may be that something similar is indicated in the University of Waterloo's ceremony or statutes, although it's also possible it's just traditional phrasing without anything formal behind it nowadays.

Comment: +1 for this answer. Almost 30 years after obtaining a doctorate from Oxford (and missing the ceremony), I finally learned some subtle details about my degree, of which I was not aware before. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## Obligations of a Degree-Holder

It seems reasonable that the degree-conferring institution would expect the following of those whom it grants degrees to:

- Maintain or enhance the reputation of your school.
- Maintain or enhance the reputation of your earned degree.
- Support the education of others.
- Education is privilege. A degree typically brings wealth and power to its owner. Do what others cannot do to make the world a better place.
- A higher degree implies understanding, and the world holds you to a higher standard because of it. Use your understanding to bring understanding to others.

It might be worth contacting your institution to see how they would articulate these obligations. (If you do, please share!)

## Useful Article

There's a thoughtful article written about this by Dr. Stephen R. Briggs, president of Berry College. You can read it [here](http://www.berry.edu/uploadedFiles/Website/President/_Assets/Documents/Essays/2008Spring_RightsPrivilegesandObligations.pdf). Of course, it's written for graduates of Berry College, but it applies equally well for all of us. For those interested in this topic, it's worth a skim.

TL;DR: Degree-holders' opportunities for education were given by others. Degree-holders therefore have, in a sense, an obligation to pay it forward.

Here's an excerpt:

> On average, a college degree results in higher status, higher salaries and
>   a better quality of life. As graduates accept their diplomas, I remind
>   them that they have earned this distinction – but only in part. **I
>   appeal to them also to receive and cherish this honor as a gift,
>   because others have made it possible.** Others before them sacrificed to
>   build America’s remarkable infrastructure – its institutions,
>   political and economic systems, and freedoms. Still others built Berry
>   – the financial base, facilities and programs that students today
>   receive as an inheritance.
>
> Martha Berry stands as an exemplar in this regard. Although she never
>   graduated from college herself, through a lifetime of devotion and
>   determination she made it possible for thousands of others to graduate
>   from college. **It is important that we not take for granted her efforts
>   or those of her many partners and successors.** Berry students have
>   always worked hard for their education, but they also have always
>   benefited greatly from the foresight and generosity of others.
>
> For these reasons, Berry graduates **have an obligation to build the systems
>   and structures of the future.** They need to become the pillars on which
>   communities are built by serving as leaders in local agencies, schools
>   and churches. They should open doors for those who need assistance and
>   direction. **They ought to provide a fitting return on the investment
>   that others have made in them. In so doing, Berry’s graduates affirm
>   that those of us who are privileged should strive all the more not to
>   act privileged. Rights and privileges should advance what one gives,
>   not what one gets.**

Comment: I downvoted this, because you have claimed a degree holder is obliged to do a number of things which they clearly are not. Why should a degree holder feel any obligation to maintain or enhance the reputation of their school?

Comment: @MJeffryes: I think it's reasonable to assume most schools would consider that to be an implicit obligation. Besides that, what other obligations I listed do you take issue with? Remember, this question is about the expectations/obligations the school has for degree-holders—not just what you think these expectations/obligations *should* be.

Comment: If I don't promote or enhance the reputation of the school (or I even disparage it), then what consequences are there? If there are none, then it isn't an obligation.

Comment: @MJeffryes: Just because a person acts against an expectation/obligation doesn't make the expectation go away. Neither does the lack of consequence(s). It may change people's behavior, but the ideal is untouched. I was issued a driver's license with the obligation not to break the law while driving (e.g. by speeding). I could drive a car at twice the speed limit in the middle of nowhere, where I'm certain to not be issued a speeding ticket, but the lack of enforcement doesn't negate the expectation or obligation.

Comment: That's a very silly comparison. Laws are the ultimate example of an obligation. They are publicly disseminated, along with the penalties for breaking them. In contrast, my university has never told me I'm supposed to do any of the things that you have listed, and there are no consequences for failing to do them.

Comment: @MJeffryes: We ought to put this in a separate discussion thread.... (I would, but don't know how.) True: there *are* consequences for speeding. That's why my example was of somebody driving where they wouldn't get caught—no consequences.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57361/discussion-between-jvriesem-and-mjeffryes).

Answer (score 0):

I would think the obligations include honesty about any subject matter in which your degree says you have some expertise.